# Overlapping stacked density plots

Tags: r, plot, probability-density, density-plot, stacked-chart

I'm trying to achieve a similar plot to this one, using R's native plot command.

[image]

I was able to get something similar with the code below, however, I'd like the density polygons to overlap. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

```
data = lapply(1:5, function(x) density(rnorm(100, mean = x)))

par(mfrow=c(5,1))
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  plot(data[[i]], xaxt='n', yaxt='n', main='', xlim=c(-2, 8), xlab='', ylab='', bty='n', lwd=1)
  polygon(data[[i]], col=rgb(0,0,0,.4), border=NA)
  abline(h=0, lwd=0.5)
}
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: You cannot do this with `par(mfrow=...)`. Need to ratchet up your polygon's x offset.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do it something like the following. I plot the densities in the same plot but add an integer to the y values. To make them overlapping i multiply by a constant factor `fac`.

```
# Create your toy data
data <- lapply(1:5, function(x) density(rnorm(100, mean = x)))

fac <- 5  # A factor to make the densities overlap

# We make a empty plot
plot(1, type = "n", xlim = c(-3, 10), ylim = c(1, length(data) + 2),
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")  

# Add each density, shifted by i and scaled by fac
for(i in 1:length(data)){
  lines(  data[[i]]$x, fac*data[[i]]$y + i)
  polygon(data[[i]]$x, fac*data[[i]]$y + i, col = rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.4), border = NA)
  abline(h = i, lwd = 0.5)
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @by0 No problem, I'm glad I could help. You might want play around with the plot `ylim` and the value of `fac` to get the output just right. Also note, that it plots from the bottom up.

Comment: I changed it so it plots from the top to bottom and put it in a function (see updated question). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

(Note: This content was previously edited into the Question and was written by [@by0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312519/by0).)

Thanks to @AEBilgrau, I quickly put together this function which works really nicely.  Note: you need to play around with the factor `fac` depending on your data.

```
stacked.density <- function(data, fac = 3, xlim, col = 'black', 
                            alpha = 0.4, show.xaxis = T, 
                            xlab = '', ylab = ''){
  xvals = unlist(lapply(data, function(d) d$x))
  if(missing(xlim)) xlim=c(min(xvals), max(xvals))

  col = sapply(col, col2alpha, alpha)
  if(length(col) == 1) col = rep(col, length(data))

  plot(1, type = "n", xlim = xlim, ylim = c(1,length(data) + 2),
       yaxt='n', bty='n', xaxt=ifelse(show.xaxis, 'l', 'n'), xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab)

  z = length(data):1
  for(i in 1:length(data)){
    d = data[[ z[i] ]]
    lines(d$x, fac*d$y + i, lwd=1)
    polygon(d$x, fac*d$y+ i, col=col[i], border=NA)
    abline(h = i, lwd=0.5)
  }
}

data <- lapply(1:5, function(x) density(rnorm(100, mean = x)))
stacked.density(data, col=c('red', 'purple', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow'), alpha=0.3, show.xaxis=T)
```

outputs:

[image]